# Laravel - Multiple query function to multiple eager loaded relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if there's a solution to a multiple closure loading two hasOne relationships. With one relationship (personaldata) I only needed some columns, and second relationship (userfile) having a where clause.
It works if I either remove the select from personaldata or remove the where clause from userfile, otherwise having two closures renders one of them with null value.

```
 $user = Users::with(['personaldata' => function($a) {
                    $a->select('first_name', 'title_name', 'last_name', 'street_address', 'city', 'state', 'country_code', 'zip_code', 'telephone_data', 'skype', 'per_street_address', 'per_city', 'per_state', 'per_country_code', 'per_zip_code');
                },
                'userfile' => function($b) {
                    $b->where('type', '1');
                }
                ])
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code like this :

```
$user = Users::with(['personaldata' => function($query) {
            $query->select('first_name', 'title_name', 'last_name', 'street_address', 'city', 'state', 'country_code', 'zip_code', 'telephone_data', 'skype', 'per_street_address', 'per_city', 'per_state', 'per_country_code', 'per_zip_code');
        }])
        ->with(['userfile' => function($query) {
            $query->where('type', '1');
        }])
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->get();
```

Comment: Why? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: I was here just to see if multiple ->with() methods were allowed, and they are, thanks.